# Real-Time Buffer Too Full (FFMPEG)

Tags: ffmpeg, buffer, capture

So I've been having this issue with ffmpeg, it has been a journey getting the hardware and command to actually do what I want, but I still have one problem.

Sometimes when I'm recording I just start dropping frames like crazy, this can be after an hour of recording or even ten hours in... Everything will be working fine and then suddenly I'll start dropping frames due to "real-time buffer too full or near too full". This happens regardless of how low I put the bitrate, and the buffer size is high as it will allow, eventually I'll just start dropping frames. Almost seems like it could be like a power saving feature kicking in but it's too inconsistent it seems. Like I said sometimes I can go 10 hours without having this issue.

Any ideas?

Here is my block of code:

```
ffmpeg -guess_layout_max 0 -y -f dshow -video_size 3440x1440 -rtbufsize 2147.48M -pixel_format nv12 -framerate 200 ^
-i video="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)":audio="SPDIF/ADAT (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" -map 0:0,0:1 -map 0:1 ^
-preset: llhp -codec:v h264_nvenc -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 250M -maxrate:v 250M -minrate:v 250M -bufsize:v 250M -b:a 320k ^
-ac 2 -r 100 -async 1 -vsync 1 -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -f segment C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\PC%02d.mp4 ^
-guess_layout_max 0 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -i audio="Analog (3+4) (RME Fireface UC)" -map 1:0 -b:a 320k -ac 2 ^
-af "adelay=200|200" -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -f segment C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\Voices\Theirs\TPC%02d.wav ^
-guess_layout_max 0 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -i audio="Analog (5+6) (RME Fireface UC)" -map 2:0 -b:a 320k -ac 2 ^
-af "adelay=825|825" -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -f segment C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\Voices\Mine\MPC%02d.wav
```

Here is the error, it repeated around 300 times before locking up ffmpeg forcing my to quit before starting the recording again:

```
[dshow @ 0000019a596bdcc0] real-time buffer [Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)] [video input] too full or near too full (62% of size: 2147480000 [rtbufsize parameter])! frame dropped!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it,

thought the solution would be to encode h.265 which wasn't working at all for some reason, thought it might be my build so I got the latest nightly build. Still couldn't get h.265 working so I went back to h.264 and started receiving a new warning I had never seen before telling me that my "thread queue size" was too low. After another few hours of trial and error / finding out there is a thread queue size per input I eventually got this block of code:

```
ffmpeg -y -thread_queue_size 5096 -guess_layout_max 0 -f dshow -video_size 3440x1440 -rtbufsize 2147.48M -framerate 200 ^
-pixel_format nv12 -i video="Video (00 Pro Capture HDMI 4K+)":audio="SPDIF/ADAT (1+2) (RME Fireface UC)" -map 0:0,0:1 ^
-map 0:1 -preset: llhp -c:v h264_nvenc -pix_fmt nv12 -b:v 250M -minrate 250M -maxrate 250M -bufsize 250M -b:a 320k -ac 2 ^
-r 100 -async 1 -vsync 1 -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -f segment C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\PC%02d.mp4 ^
-guess_layout_max 0 -thread_queue_size 5096 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -i audio="Analog (3+4) (RME Fireface UC)" -map 1:0 ^
-b:a 320k -ac 2 -af "adelay=200|200" -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -f segment ^
C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\Voices\Theirs\TPC%02d.wav ^
-guess_layout_max 0 -thread_queue_size 5096 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -i audio="Analog (5+6) (RME Fireface UC)" -map 2:0 ^
-b:a 320k -ac 2 -af "adelay=825|825" -segment_time 600 -segment_wrap 9 -f segment ^
C:\Users\djcim\Videos\PC\Voices\Mine\MPC%02d.wav
```

Basically I added -thread_queue_size 5096 to each input, haven't dropped a frame on ingestion since. Everything stays in sync, footage is buttery smooth.